# Get rid of core data warnings in older model versions

Tags: ios, core-data, compiler-warnings

I am getting core data warning MOMC_NO_INVERSE_RELATIONSHIP_WARNINGS for some of my attributes as I did not set inverse relationships for some.. Now I have cleared them in my newer model version but still the warnings are shown for the older version..

Looks I cannot simply set the suppress warnings flag for MOMC_NO_INVERSE_RELATIONSHIP_WARNINGS in build settings which will not be of any help as this is just going to suppress all my future warnings related to this.

Is there any way i can get rid of this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no setting to disable this warning only on older model versions. You can disable it on **all** model versions, but unfortunately it's all or nothing. You can do this either on a specific model or for all models in the project.

To completely disable the warning for all models in the project, go to build settings and turn on the setting to suppress this warning.

[image]

To disable the warning for a single model, but for all versions of that model, find the file in "Build Phases" under "Compile Sources" and add the `--no-inverse-relationship-warnings` flag for the file.

[image]

Both of these are kind of a bad idea since they'll ignore any future edits that have missing inverses. But I don't think there's any other way to keep Xcode quite about old versions that have since been fixed.